# How can I wire up a Jquery plugin to a table in a partial view after ajax call

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, plugins

I have a view that uses a partial view to list items in a table.

**Main View** 
(Inside a `div`, it calls the Partial View)

```
<div id="divList">
    @Html.Action("_list")
</div>
```

**Partial View** 
(Shows a list of items in a table, and it uses the `tablesorter` plugin to sort/filter items in the table on client side)

```
<table id="tblList" class="tablesorter-bootstrap">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Item Header</th>
        </tr>
    </thead> 
    <tbody>
        @foreach (var item in Model)
        {
            <td>@item.Name</td>
        }
    </tbody>
</table>
```

**Javascript** 
In the Main View

```
<script type="text/javascript">

        $(document).ready(function () {

            $("#tblList").tablesorter({
                theme: 'bootstrap',
                headerTemplate: '{content} {icon}',
                widgets: ['filter']

            });
        });
</script>
```

### What I want to do

In the main view, I have some ajax calls. 
Since the partial view gets refreshed every time an ajax call is made, the `tblList` table loses the `tablesorter` effects after the ajax call. 
I understand the reason why it loses the effect.

Is there any way to keep the `tablesorter` effect after ajax calls?

I've tried the following methods:

- Moved `$("#tblList").tablesorter()` in the partial view, but it loses the plugin effect
- Refresh/reload the main view after ajax calls. This **works** fine but the only thing that kind of bothers me is that it takes a couple of seconds to see the plugin effect in the table.
- I know something like `$(document).on('click', '#btn', function(){});` could work if it's just a button and tried to go with this approach, but I'm not sure what I can do with a plugin...

### EDIT

As suggested by Shyju, I've added the following and it does exactly what I wanted with no time lag!

```
function enableTableSort($element)
{
    $element.tablesorter({
        theme: 'bootstrap',
        headerTemplate: '{content} {icon}',
        widgets: ['filter']
    });
}

enableTableSort($("#tblList"));

$(document).on('click', '#btnAction', function() {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'url',
        type: 'POST',
        data: JASON.stringify(list: list),
        contentType: 'application/json',
        success: function (data) {
            $("#divList").html(data);
            enableTableSort($("#tblList"));
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to re-enable the plugin once the ajax call loads the new markup.

Something like this

```
$(function () {

    function enableTableSort($element) {
        $element.tablesorter({
            theme: 'bootstrap'
        });
    }

    enableTableSort($("#myTable"));

    //Let's say we have button which makes ajax call and reload table
    $("#reloadBtn").click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();  // to be safe 

        $("#tblContainer").load("@Url.Action("GetList")", function () {                 
            enableTableSort($("#myTable"));
        });

    });

});
```

Comment: Thank you. So, does it have to let user click the `reload` button?

Comment: That is just an example, the essence is, you need to rebind the plugin once ajax call is done.

Comment: Ok. Thank you! I'll try this now.